# How to force WebBrowser Control to continue the script?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm a newbie in C#.
I set URL for WebBrowser and when i run it.It's giving a DialogBox like this:[image]>

How can i avoid from this? I mean this dialogbox shouldn't appear when i run it.

Comment: Finally ,I found a solution to my own question:this.webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set browser-control's ScriptErrorsSuppressed property.

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed.aspx):

> Type: System.Boolean true if the
>   control does not display its dialog
>   boxes; otherwise, false. The default
>   is false.

Comment: sorry, seems you found it when i just posted the answer :/